# Looking for advice on making an electric furnace that can handle 10kg/22lb of aluminium

Tags: metalworking, metal, casting

Can anyone recommend a method/tutorial for building an electric furnace that has the capacity to handle around 10kg/22lb of aluminium?

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts. I streamlined your question to just the portion that is on-topic (asking for product recommendations or where to buy is off-topic).  Good luck with this.

Comment: My honest advice is not to DIY such a furnace. Aluminium has a high melting temperature, which means: 1) your furnace has to be able to handle such temperatures without malfunctioning and potentially injuring you or bystanders and 2) you have to be able to handle extremely hot molten metal safely. Any accident can quickly cause life-changing injuries or death.

Comment: I think that is beyond a "do it yourself" project. Possible surplus equipment could be found on the internet ? It would require more electric power than is available in a home.

Comment: Smaller melting furnaces that I have seen are induction , not resistance heat.

Comment: Hi Cautiouslyoptimistic, please note we don't write complete tutorials here. Can you specify your question by adding more details and let us know where you run into problems? I'll close this question for now. Welcome to Arts & Crafts!